# How can I use process substitution strings in BASH?

Tags: bash, process-substitution

I know I can do something like

```
cat <(cat somefile)
```

But I want to build up a string of `<()`.
So:

```
for file in *.file; do
    mySubs="${mySubs} <(cat ${file})"
done

cat ${mySubs} #cat <(cat 1.file) <(cat 2.file) ... <(cat something.file)
```

Without having to use `eval`.

Comment: You don't. `<(...)` isn't an expression; it's part of the shell's syntax. You would need to use `eval` (with all its accompanying brittleness and security concerns) to do what you want.

Comment: @chepner Sorry edited to mention I did not want to use `eval`.

Comment: What's the point of `<(cat somefile)` rather than just `file`?

Comment: BTW, I *do* already have answers on this site showing how to do this with `eval` safely (which requires some work), and/or how to use recursive functions to achieve something comparable.

Comment: @VietLe Wise choice :) That's why I didn't post an answer showing how to use it.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy He likely wants to do more than just cat the file...  `<( cat ${f} | sed | tr | grep) `

Comment: @ABrothers, yes, I assume as much. My comment above was to point out that a better example would have showcased that intent.

Comment: @ABrothers, ...aside: `cat ${f}` is quite buggy (splitting the filename in `f` on spaces and treating each result from that split as a glob), in addition to being inefficient (requiring an extra process and forcing `sed` to read from a FIFO rather than direct from the actual file; not that big a performance hit for sed, but can be a huge one for `tail` or `tac` or `sort` on large files). Much better to run `<"$f" sed | ...`

Answer (score 2):

Use named pipes directly. Use `mktemp` to create temporary file names for each pipe so that you can remove them after you are done.

```
fifos=()
for f in file1 file2 file3; do
    t=$(mktemp)
    mkfifo "$t"
    pipes+=("$t")
    someCommand "$f" > "$t" &
done

someOtherCommand "${pipes[@]}"
rm "${pipes[@]}"
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming `cat` is a standin for a more complicated command. Here, I'm explicitly wrapping it to show that:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

someCommand() { echo "Starting file $1"; cat "$1"; echo "Ending file $1"; }

wrap_all() {

  ## STAGE 1: Assemble the actual command we want to run
  local fd cmd_len retval
  local -a cmd fds fd_args
  cmd_len=$1; shift
  while (( cmd_len > 0 )); do
    cmd+=( "$1" )
    cmd_len=$((cmd_len - 1))
    shift
  done

  ## STAGE 2: Open an instance of someCommand for each remaining argument
  local fd; local -a fds
  fds=( )
  for arg; do
    exec {fd}< <(someCommand "$arg")
    fds+=( "$fd" )
    fd_args+=( "/dev/fd/$fd" )
  done

  ## STAGE 3: Actually run the command
  "${cmd[@]}" "${fd_args[@]}"; retval=$?

  ## STAGE 4: Close all the file descriptors
  for fd in "${fds[@]}"; do
    exec {fd}>&-
  done

  return "$retval"
}
```

Invocation as:

```
echo "one" >one.txt; echo "two" >two.txt
wrap_all 1 cat one.txt two.txt
```

...which outputs:

```
Starting file one.txt
one
Ending file one.txt
Starting file two.txt
two
Ending file two.txt
```

Note that this requires bash 4.1 for automatic FD allocation support (letting us avoid the need for named pipes).